# WebSitePanel settings causing crash?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

Using Websitepanel ver1.1 on my hosting provider and trying to adjust a website (ASP.NET MVC2) to run under .NET 4 integrated pipeline mode.

Every time i apply this setting i get the following error (to be correct: it doesn't matter if i choose 4.0 or 4.0 integrated pipeline):

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
Server was unable to process request.
---> Error executing 'UPDATE' task on 'my_website.com' WEB_SITE
---> Server was unable to process request.
---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at WebsitePanel.EnterpriseServer.esWebServers.UpdateWebSite(WebSite site)
at WebsitePanel.Portal.WebSitesEditSite.SaveWebSite()
```

Is there something I can do about this? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Setting back to .NET 2.0 or 2.0 pipeline works like a charm!

Comment: Did you ever get this up and running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a VPS, log into the server Try changing the application pool to 4.0 classic instead of 4.0 integrated from IIS manager >> sites >> basic settings. Also make sure that MVC2 is compatible with asp.net 4.

You can edit the corresponding web.config page to change the asp version by changing the corresponding version line to 4 instead of 2.

Please let us know by changing the application pool to 4.0 classic. If you are not having administrator password, Ask your hosting provider support to do this.

Also ask them to check the event viewer logs to know further about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is  Websitepanel version 1.1

To solve this error, you need to request your hosting provider to upgrade the websitepanel version to 2.0

.NET 4.0 provides better support for aplications, also .NET 2.0 has been deprecated by several web hosting providers.